# Split sentence into character limited arrays

Tags: php

I'm currently attempting to split a sentence into a character limited arrays. The sentences are split into words by using `explode` and then each word is added to an array of sentences if the length of string of the current index is less than ie. 135. But i'm currently having an issue with getting the limit right, Im not too sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

function parseDefinition($def){

    $tweets = [];
    $index = 0;
    $wordsArr = explode(" ", $def);
    $sentence = "";
    $length = 135;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($wordsArr); $i++){
        if (!isset($sentences[$index])){
            $sentences[$index] = $wordsArr[$i];
        }else{
            $sentenceLength =  strlen($sentences[$index]);
            if ($sentenceLength <= $length){
                $sentence = $sentences[$index] . " " . $wordsArr[$i];
                $sentences[$index] = $sentence;
            }else{
                $index ++;
                $sentence = $wordsArr[$i];
                $sentences[$index] = $sentence;
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($sentences);

}

parseDefinition("Vikings follows the adventures of Ragnar Lothbrok, the greatest hero of his age. The series tells the sagas of Ragnar's band of Viking brothers and his family, as he rises to become King of the Viking tribes. As well as being a fearless warrior, Ragnar embodies the Norse traditions of devotion to the gods. Legend has it that he was a direct descendant of Odin, the god of war and warriors.");


?>
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what the issue is. Is it that the sentence arrays end up longer than 135 chars

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes the length of the string in the arrays are longer than the specified length

Comment: So a sentence must be 135 chars OR LESS right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats right

Comment: that's because you check the string length before concatenating your string , your string length until the words 'band of viking' is 134 so when you check length and find out that the length is 134 your condition going right and then concatenate 'brothers' , check out the @RiggsFolly answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just forgetting to add the size of the new word you were going to add to the existing sentence before deciding to add it or start a new sentence

See mods

```
function parseDefinition($def){

    $tweets = [];
    $index = 0;
    $wordsArr = explode(" ", $def);
    $sentence = "";
    $length = 135;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($wordsArr); $i++){
        if (!isset($sentences[$index])){
            $sentences[$index] = $wordsArr[$i];
        }else{
            // Add the new words size to the calc before adding to sentence
            // plus 1 for the space you are also going to add
             if (strlen($sentences[$index]) + strlen($wordsArr[$i]) + 1 <= $length){
                $sentence = $sentences[$index] . " " . $wordsArr[$i];
                $sentences[$index] = $sentence;
            }else{
                $index ++;
                $sentence = $wordsArr[$i];
                $sentences[$index] = $sentence;
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($sentences);

}

parseDefinition("Vikings follows the adventures of Ragnar Lothbrok, the greatest hero of his age. The series tells the sagas of Ragnar's band of Viking brothers and his family, as he rises to become King of the Viking tribes. As well as being a fearless warrior, Ragnar embodies the Norse traditions of devotion to the gods. Legend has it that he was a direct descendant of Odin, the god of war and warriors.");
```

Result

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(134) "Vikings follows the adventures of Ragnar Lothbrok, the greatest hero of his age. The series tells the sagas of Ragnar's band of Viking"
  [1] =>
  string(130) "brothers and his family, as he rises to become King of the Viking tribes. As well as being a fearless warrior, Ragnar embodies the"
  [2] =>
  string(125) "Norse traditions of devotion to the gods. Legend has it that he was a direct descendant of Odin, the god of war and warriors."
}
```